# How to customize color in`HighlightImage`

Tags: visualization

I am trying to visualize the semantic mask, the example code on official guide is as followings:

[image]

I am wondering how to cusomize my own color pallete like Python Matplotlib?

Comment: Check `ColorReplace`.

Comment: Take a look at the `Advanced Visualization` section in the [documentation](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Dilated-ResNet-22-Trained-on-Cityscapes-Data). It shows how the colors can be customized.